# Why Facebook Login API don't ask email access?

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

Guys I have a custom button which trigger an FB.login() event but I can't get email info, facebook don't ask an email access to user and return *name*, *id* fields

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  console.log(response)
  if (response.authResponse) {
    FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email', function(data) {
      console.log(data)
      if ((typeof data.email === 'undefined') ||(data.email == '') || (data.email == null)) {
        M.toast({html: "You dont't give an email access, we are can't register you without email. Sorry :("});
          return false;
       }
       window.flags.signin = {
         status: true,
         name_surname: data.name,
         email: data.email,
         login_type: 'facebook',
         id: data.id
       }
      // back-end request func   
      window.flags.submitFunc('veriler='+JSON.stringify(window.flags.signin));
    }, { scope: 'id,name,email'});
  }
  else {
    M.toast({html: 'User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.'});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repair it,
I change this line

```
{ scope: 'id,name,email'}
```

**to**

```
{ scope: 'email'}
```

and it's started ask to email access